# Min between abs of dot product and norm

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, convex-analysis, vector-analysis

Let $f,g : \mathbb{R}^n \to [0,\infty)$ be two convex functions such that $f(x) = \left|p \cdot x \right|$ for some $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ ( the absolute value of the dot product between $p$ and $x$) and $g(x) = \left\| x\right\|_2$ denote the $l_2$ norm of $x$.

I wish to show whether $ h(x) = \min \left\lbrace f(x), g(x) \right\rbrace$ is convex function.
For such function ($h(x)$), if i compute the second derivative to check whether the Hessian is positive semi-definite then i get that its always zero yet i am not sure of this result.

Please advise.

Comment: First note that by a rotation you can assume that $p=(|p|, 0,\ldots,0)$.

Comment: ok, however how can this can help establish that for any point $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $h(x)$ is convex?

Comment: Another easy thing to say is that, if $|p|\le 1$ then $h(x)=f(x)$ and so it is convex. The interesting case is therefore $|p|>1$. I think that $h$ is convex also in this case. To prove it, I also think that it is enough to: i) consider $p=(|p|, 0,\ldots, 0)$;  ii) limit ourselves to the case $x_1\ge 0 ,x_2\ge 0\ldots$; iii)show that $h(\alpha z_+ + \beta z_-)\ge \alpha h(z_+)+\beta h(z_-)$ for $\alpha, \beta\ge 0$, $\alpha+\beta=1$ and $ z_\pm$ belonging to $\{ x_2^2+\ldots + x_n^2 \ge \pm (|p|^2-1)x_1^2\}$ respectively. This is not a great hint, but at least it is a starting point, I hope

Comment: Can it not be shown using the second derivative (showing that Hessian is positive semi definite matrix) ???

Comment: The problem is that this function does not seem to be differentiable along the junction. It is the pasting of $\|x\|$ and $|p||x_1|$ which are convex, but one should check what happens where they join, that's where that condition comes from

Comment: I see, thanks for your help thus far, yet is it possible for such function to have a convex sub-level set? (even if the function is not convex)